# I want to change my quaternions coordinate to rotation coordinates

Tags: reactjs, react-native, quaternions, react-360

I am getting the quaternions coordinate `[x,y,z,w]` from a sensor. I want to change that coordinate so that I can rotate my React VR application scene to rotating that scene. I need to change the quaternions coordinate to the rotation coordinate. But the rotation here is not smooth for the smooth rotation "quaternion coordinate" must be converted to rotation.

```
import {VRInstance} from 'react-vr-web';
import scene from 'three.js';
//let us assume x,y,z,w are my coordinate in quaternion formate which I //am taking through web socket
function init(bundle, parent, options) 
{
 //scene=new scene()//three.js

  const vr = new VRInstance(bundle, 'musical_exp_react_vr_pusher', 
 parent, {
    // Add custom options here
    ...options,
  });
  vr.render = function() {
  //but its not working as I took the quaternion coordiate
 //smoothness is not there
 vr.scene.rotationx=x;
 vr.scene.rotationx=y;
 vr.scene.rotationx=z;

 //it is also not working
 vr.scene.quaternion.x=x;
 vr.scene.quaternion.y=y;
 vr.scene.quaternion.z=z;

  // Any custom behavior you want to perform on each frame goes here
  };
  // Begin the animation loop
  vr.start();
  return vr;
 }

 window.ReactVR = {init};
```

The main problem is that I need to find the rotation axis coordinate from quaternion coordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion) and [Euler angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles) are two separate concepts, and cannot be converted via simple assignment. Depending on the type of Euler angles your framework is using, the [conversion algorithm can be a bit complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles).

Three.js implements this conversion in the [Euler.setFromQuaternion()](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Euler.setFromQuaternion) method.

However, looking at the documentation of three.js, it seems the [quaternion assignment should work](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.quaternion) as you intend - you just need to assign all 4 elements of the quaternion (your code is missing the W element).

Comment: the conversion algorithm can be a bit complex but its working I tried it but as I convert the quaternion coordinate to the rotation axis its giving me only 3DOF(degree of freedom) but I need 6DOF so I will have to use that three.js implementation So after trying it I will let you know the result .Yet I did not use the predefine function the THREE.js like setFromQuaternion and all function hope it may work. Thank you so much :).